# gulp not injecting compiled css

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

I am using browser-sync and sass among other plugins, but for some reason the browser-sync doesn't inject the css, the sass is getting compiled and being watched but that's it.

here is my gulp file:

```
'use strict';
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const pug = require('gulp-pug');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const rename = require('gulp-rename');

const reload = browserSync.reload;

// Compile sass files to css
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./assets/css/*.sass')
      .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 15 versions'],
        cascade: true
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./site/css'))
      .pipe(browserSync.stream())
});
// Compile pug files to html
gulp.task('pug', () =>{
  return gulp.src('_pugfiles/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_include'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./site'))
});

gulp.task('js', function () {
  gulp.src("./assets/js/function.js")
  .pipe(rename("js/function.js"))
  .pipe(gulp.dest("./site"));
});
// the working directory
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['sass', 'pug', 'js'] ,function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./site"
        },

    });
});
// Watch files compiling
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./assets/css/*.sass', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('./_pugfiles/*.pug', ['pug']);
  gulp.watch('./site/*.html').on('change', reload);
  gulp.watch('./assets/js/*.js', ['js']);
  gulp.watch('./site/js/*.js').on('change', reload)
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'browser-sync']);
```

and this is my folder structure:

1. app

   - _include
   - _pugfiles
   - _site
   - _assets

     - css
     - img
     - js
   - node_modules
   - site

so here is what i have tried so far, rebuilding it again, removed few watch tasks
also tried `.pipe(browsersync.stream({match: '**/*.css'}));` and `files: ['!**/*.maps.css']` to ignore css map files.

maybe i have tried other things but i can't remember, i spent most of yesterday trying to fix it.

Comment: Try this at the end of your 'sass' task  ::      .pipe(reload({ stream:true }));
and let us know if that helps.

Comment: Still no change at all.

Comment: So after running the default task you modify a sass file and can verify that site/css/*.css is changed correctly?  But the resultant css file(s) is not reloaded to the served page?  And the htmI page links to that css file? don't really see anything wrong with your code.  Is 'last 15 versions' really an acceptable option to autoprefixer?  Does it work if you remove the autoprefixer pipe?

Comment: yes the css is changed correctly and the autoprefixer is working i didn't notice the 'last 15 versions' part because i changed it and still nothing, so

Comment: i ended up rebuilding the whole thing but without pug and i have added bower this time and it is working fine now, so thank you for your help :)